# how to get hertz tones in bash

Tags: bash, sound

So I have (sometimes one) mutable 1200 Hertz tones playing, what I want to detect is if there are more tones than one or if the tone is bigger than N secents (as in time I do not know how to spell this).

Comment: To confirm, you want a bash script that can “listen” to tones and report how long they run for? 

Comment: Yes, that is correct.